# Need help fixing sql syntax error after WP 3.2 upgrade

Tags: database, upgrade

I'm using a plugin that failed after upgrade to wp3.2.

The error log shows:

> WordPress database error You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1 for `query SELECT post_id, meta_value, post_status FROM bxxoai_postmeta LEFT JOIN bxxoai_posts ON post_id=bxxoai_posts.ID WHERE post_status='publish' AND meta_key='wpfp_favorites' AND meta_value > 0 ORDER BY ROUND(meta_value) DESC LIMIT 0,  made by require, require_once, include, get_header, locate_template, load_template, require_once, get_sidebar, locate_template, load_template, require_once, wpfp_widget_view, wpfp_list_most_favorited`

mysql version I used is 5.0.92-community

I'm clueless with database, can anyone please teach or help explain to me what needed to be done to fix this?

Comment: What plugin caused this error?

Comment: wp-favorite-post, only specific to how it handles the query to get the most favorited list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into this as well... I am using the SQL query, but not the wpfp_list_most_favorited() function, so this may or may not work for you, but worth a shot. Try updating the SQL query in wp-favorite-posts.php (around line 206) from:

```
$query = "SELECT post_id, meta_value, post_status FROM $wpdb->postmeta";
```

To:

```
$query = "SELECT post_id, meta_value, meta_key, post_status FROM $wpdb->postmeta";
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: only upvoted before, now the checkmark. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you can log in to your WP Admin, remove the plugin from there. Otherwise, go through FTP and remove the offending plugin through wp/wp-content/plugins/

After removing, your site should run properly without the error.

Comment: thanks but no thanks. My question is specific to need sql syntax help, not to dump the plugin completely.